# Meaning of several peaks of information curves in GRM

Tags: interpretation, item-response-theory

I fitted my data to GRM, got the information curves and try to interprete the pictures.

[image: Here's what I've got]

I'm new to IRT and still don't get a lot of things. Here I can observe that the items are pretty good and measure what we actually meant. The best item is Q15_3, but what do the peaks mean on this green curve, why is there a lot of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items that you are analysing likely consist of more than 2 response categories, falling into the topic of *polytomous* IRT models (as opposed to *dichotomous*, which IRT is commonly presented for).

The reason you are seeing multiple peaks is because each response category is providing a unique piece of information about the underlying ability based upon where the points of maximum inflection occur in the probability functions. For dichotmous models, which have a single inflection point (e.g., the 1-4PL models), the information function has only a single peak, while for non-monotonic probability response models and polytomous models multiple inflection points can occur, resulting in information functions which rise and fall with respect to $\theta$. The effect becomes even more pronounced when the so-called `difficulty` or intercept parameters in polytomous models are farther away from each other.

For a visualisation of this effect, try manipulating the GUI that ships with the `mirt` package by passing `mirt::itemplot(shiny = TRUE)`, changing the IRT class to `'graded'`, selecting the output plot as `'info'`, and moving the intercept/slope parameters manually with the supplied sliders. You should also see the relationship with the classical parameterization in the output as well, though that can be manipulated directly too.